# Trying to get the object key of a nested JSON object

Tags: javascript, json, object

I need to get a list of all the key names in the following JSON object:

```
var myJSON = [
    {
        "Employees_Name": "Bill Sanders",
        "Work_plan_during_my_absence": "Work from home",
        "Assigned To-Manager Approval": [
            "mymanager@gmail.com"
        ],
        "AbsenceVacation_Summary": [
            {
                "Computed_Leave_Days": 2,
                "From_Date": "2018-08-20",
                "To_Date": "2018-08-21",
                "Id": "Shccbcc230_a30f_11e8_9afa_25436d674c51"
            }
        ],
        "Leave_Type": "Work from Home",
        "Reporting_Manager": "My Manager",
        "Total_Days": 2,
    }
]
```

When I use the Object.keys method, it retrieves only the top level key names:

```
var keys_arr = Object.keys(myJSON[0]);
console.log(keys_arr);
```

The result is an array:

```
"[ 'Employees_Name', 'Work_plan_during_my_absence', 'Assigned To-Manager
Approval', 'AbsenceVacation_Summary', 'Leave_Type', 'Reporting_Manager',
'Total_Days']"
```

The key names that are missing are the ones inside of 'AbsenceVacation_Summary'.

I think what I need to do is loop through the array of names returned and see if the value is an object or an array...but I don't know how to do this.  Please advise.

Comment: You can recursively collect names--iterate over the keys and collect the names as you're doing, but if the value is also an array, recursively collect names from that subarray.

Comment: What structure are you looking for from the result?  For instance, if a  key appears in multiple locations, do you want it to appear once in the result or many times?

Comment: What output are you looking for? Is it `["Employees_Name","Work_plan_during_my_absence","Assigned To-Manager Approval","AbsenceVacation_Summary","Computed_Leave_Days","From_Date","To_Date","Id","Leave_Type","Reporting_Manager","Total_Days"]` ?

Answer (score 1):

You're right you need to walk your object structure recursively to discover nested objects and collects their keys:

```
function collectKeys(inputObject, outputKeys) {
    if (Array.isArray(inputObject)) {
        for(let i = 0; i < inputObject.length; i++) {
            collectKeys(inputObject[i], outputKeys);
        }
    } else if (typeof inputObject === 'object') {
        Object.keys(inputObject).forEach(function(key) {
            outputKeys.push(key);
            collectKeys(outputKeys[key], outputKeys);
        });
    }
}
var collectedKeys = [];
collectKeys(myJSON, collectedKeys);
```

[Working fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/tb402rz3/3/)

Result will show in console

**References**

- [javascript typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof)
- [javascript Array.isArray](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray)
- [javascript Array.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)